Name Snapshot same as AMI, creating it manually via CLI
I am creating AMI to backup some AWS VMs via AWS CLI, the AMI name, description, everything is OK. However the snapshots it creates are not using the same tag or name I need.
I found a previous post (very similar case): How to name snapshots as well as ami's in amazon date lifecycle manager
It mentions I should use  "Copy tags from source" in the Lifecycle policy. Should copy name of the volume to the snapshot, as volume name is a 'tag'.  but my scenario is not the same, Im creating the images manually via AWS cli, then problem is that those are not getting deleted (the snapshot) as needed (this is done automatically)
Any help?
Im currently creating my AMI as follow:
aws ec2 create-image \
    --instance-id i-0e3a7bXXXXXXXXXX\
    --name "EXT-XXXXXX-01" \
    --description "1052024" \
    --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=image,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=EXT-XXXXX-01}]' \
    --no-reboot 

And as I said the AMI gets created correctly, but the Snapshot dont get the same name, and the row name shows (-) when you filter it.

Include the CLI command you use to create snapshots. This helps in understanding and providing a precise solution.
